# Massive "voting corrected" reversal ─ but different numbers shown in different places

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

It looks like someone has been caught using votes inappropriately; in the reputation drop-down box I see a −50 rep adjustment for serial voting:

[image: -50 Serial voting was reversed]

But on the reputation page I see −726:

[image: reversal -726 Voting corrected]

That's a lot! But I don't *think* my rep has actually gone down by 700+ overnight. That'd be about 20% of my whole rep! Is this number really correct, or is it a bug?

Comment: I've had that just a few days ago - it said -230 in the rep page and then it just lowered to -120. The actual figure was 120, so I have no idea where the 230 came from.

Comment: [Posted to MSE because I think it will get more attention there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390153/1200429)

Comment: Moderators can see the voting pattern and check if there's something weird happening, but only if there's a moderator already...

Comment: Are you still seeing that message reflected that way on your end? I am not able to see any numbers that high on my end.

Comment: @SpencerG I'm now seeing -50 on the reputation page. I guess either the bug got fixed, or it was sporadic and only showed temporarily (perhaps an incorrect number got cached?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on MSE